# Interrupted upgrade of Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 gives - Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dist-upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I was upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 using `do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive`, but the upgrade halted due to a power cut and upon resuming the upgrade I was getting the following errors:

1. In the hope to resume the upgrade, upon execution of `do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive` I get:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

2. I tried to resume the installation of packages using `apt-get update --fix-missing` and I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
appstreamcli: symbol lookup error: appstreamcli: undefined symbol: AS_APPSTREAM_METADATA_PATHS
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I tried searching for solutions on Google and Stack Overflow's Websites, I got many related issues, but no one was answering the question of my exact problem, i.e. to resume an interrupted upgrade and getting the error of `appstreamcli`.

So, I am presenting how I fixed the problem.

If you have solved this problem using any other approach, you are welcome to mention it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the following steps:

First I tried purging using `sudo apt-get purge libappstream3` as [suggested here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/update-error-appstreamcli-symbol-lookup-error-4175661311/#post6039486), but this package was not found in the system.

Then, as [suggested in this blog post](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/rescuing-an-interrupted-ubuntu-upgrade/#:%7E:text=Press%20the%20left%20shift%20key,to%20use%20a%20recovery%20shell.) and [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1873713/comments/2), and I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and the installation resumed and completed without any error.

After that, I tried running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` and it worked properly and updated the packages.